# How to display objects from VueX using fetched data from an API

Tags: api, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to experiment on displaying data using `VueX` and a free API from rapidapi. Somehow I can't display or iterate through it properly in the component.

The console displays the objects correctly, but the component that's supposed to display it does not.

What am I doing wrong?

Here are the relevant codes:

**store/index.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    worldData:     
      fetch("https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com",
          "x-rapidapi-key": "mySecretKey"
        }
      })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.response.sort((a, b) => (a.country > b.country ? 1 : -1));
      console.log(data.response);
      return data.response;
    })
  },
  getters: {
    worldData: state => state.worldData,
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

**components/mycomponent.vue**

```html
<template>
      <div >  
        <div v-for="myData in $store.getters.worldData" :key="myData">{{myData}}</div>
      </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What data type is `country`? Is it a string or a number?

Comment: It's a string. and as stated above, console is actually displaying the objects correctly in inspector. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a store, the [`state`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html) property is for initial / default values. You are currently setting yours to a `Promise` which is probably not what you want.

Performing asynchronous tasks should be done via [`actions`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html) and the results committed through [`mutations`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html).

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    worldData: [] // initial value
  },
  getters: {
    worldData: state => state.worldData
  },
  mutations: {
    setWorldData: (state, worldData) => state.worldData = worldData
  },
  actions: {
    loadWorldData: async ({ commit }) => {
      // load the data via fetch
      const res = await fetch('https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics', {
        headers: {
          "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com",
          "x-rapidapi-key": "mySecretKey"
        }
      })

      // check for a successful response
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw res
      }

      // parse the JSON response
      const worldData = (await res.json()).response

      // commit the new value via the "setWorldData" mutation
      commit('setWorldData', worldData.sort((a, b) => a.country.localeCompare(b.country)))
    }
  }
})

store.dispatch('loadWorldData') // dispatch the action to load async data
export default store
```

You can execute the `dispatch` anywhere at any time to load / reload the data.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm getting a compile error with that solution. Something about unexpected token, expected "(" and pointing to loadWorldData^:. Apologies, I don't know the correct syntax for this one.

Comment: @Artvader I'd made some typos earlier. Please check again and make sure you're seeing the latest update to my answer

Comment: Compiling correctly now. Although there's a console error saying  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: worldData.sort is not a function. I'm trying to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that the property was called `response`. I've fixed my answer now